# Stack Overflow doesn't retain list item numbers in quoted sections

Tags: support, feature-request

In @aliteralmind's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24714952/2888561), he quotes some items from a numbered list in the original question.  But Stack Overflow changed all the list numbers to `1`.  The answers suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1), i.e. inserting an extra space before non-numbered lines and double line breaks, don't seem to work.  I've duplicated part of the answer below in case the answer at the link gets edited.

> 1. Is the static variables p and JFrame specific to both FirstMaster and SecondMaster, that is Master.p, FirstMaster.p and SecondMaster.p are the one and the same Point with a single memory location?

There is a single `p` that is shared ...

This is because `p` and `glass` are declared as ...

> 2. Each (instance of) First and Second Master is an independent ActionListener and needs to define the associated method - correct?

"The associated method"? What method are you referring to? ...

It's more accurate to say ...

> 3. Without the modifiers static it would be equivalent to simply copy and paste the code in Master into the First and Second and get rid of the extends?

Well, a potential beneficial side-effect of ...

In an even moderately large project, ...

So I would always choose to have ...

Comment: Link to question is bad.

Comment: @bjb568 Fixed--thanks for catching it.  Too many copy-and-pastes going on, I was bound to screw one up... :(

Comment: I doubt that they will allow arbitrary numbers, so the best thing to do is probably just not use lists like that. I edited them out.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1.

Comment: @false Already did, and in fact my question referred to it.  Was there something else there you wanted me to see?

Comment: balpha’s answer, specifically, and that you shouldn’t try to work around it. This is something that needs fixing in Markdown and its implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to answering numbered parts quoted from the question, I work around this limitation by having a single list and nesting the quoted parts within each item, like so:

1. > Is the static variables p and JFrame specific to both FirstMaster and SecondMaster, that is Master.p, FirstMaster.p and SecondMaster.p are the one and the same Point with a single memory location?

   There is a single `p` that is shared ...

   This is because `p` and `glass` are declared as ...
2. > Each (instance of) First and Second Master is an independent ActionListener and needs to define the associated method - correct?

   "The associated method"? What method are you referring to? ...

   It's more accurate to say ...
3. > Without the modifiers static it would be equivalent to simply copy and paste the code in Master into the First and Second and get rid of the extends?

   Well, a potential beneficial side-effect of ...

   In an even moderately large project, ...

   So I would always choose to have ...

Comment: [Markdown source of this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7875931a-4336-4245-8d56-4cb319590cc7/view-source)

Comment: [Examples of answers that I've posted using this technique](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210916/quoted-part-questions-in-list-format)

Comment: Nice... I didn't know you could do that.